# Using .ajax() to load remote URL - not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to load a remote URL (or rather just test to see if a remote page exists).

This works just fine:

```
$(function() {     
    $.ajax({
        url:'localtest.html',
        type: 'html',
        success: function(content,code) {
            alert(code);
            $('body').html(content);
        }
    });        
});
```

But swap in a remote URL and I get nothing:

```
$(function() {     
    $.ajax({
        url:'http://www.google.com/',
        type: 'html',
        success: function(content,code) {
            alert(code);
            $('body').html(content);
        }
    });        
});
```

Is there any way to do that?

Comment: What is the error you are getting.  Have you used Firebug to see what the error is?

Answer (score 3):

AJAX doesn't support cross domain calls, for security reasons.

The traditional way around it is using [jsonp](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP)

Answer (score 2):

Browsers prevent Ajax from accessing resources cross domain (SOP = same origin policy). It will only work if the server is configured for "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" pointing to your domain (or * or similar).

Comment: Access-Control-Allow-Origin will not work with older browsers (e.g IE) so it can not be considered reliable.

Answer (score 2):

This is because the browser won't allow cross-site requests unless the remote server explicitly allows it by sending an Access-Control-Allow-Origin header. If you just want to test existence, you might be able to load the URL in an image tag with an onload and onerror event. You won't be able to access the contents of the remote URL though; it's for security. Otherwise, for example, you could load facebook and read someone's wall without them knowing.

Answer (score -1):

This is not a right ajax call. The type should have been 'GET' assuming you are doing a retrieval operation. What should be 'html' is the dataType attribute.

```
$.ajax({
        url:'http://www.google.com/',
        type: 'GET'
        dataType: 'html',
        success:function(content,code)
        {
            alert(code);
            $('body').html(content);
        }
        });        
    });
```

and also, as anybody has added, since you are making a call to google.com, you have to provide a jsonp callback, because of same origin policy..hope that helps.

Comment: Can u have any example regarding JSONP callback. Please share .

Answer (score -1):

For security reasons,AJAX doesn't support CORS(cross origin resource sharing).

Comment: Yes, it does. CORS was designed specifically for Ajax (and then expanded for a few other things like fonts and canvas images).

Answer (score -2):

Use attribute in AJAX call.

```
crossDomain: true
```

And do make sure meta data tag of html page where you are loading contents.

Comment: That won't do anything. It only matters if you are making a same origin request which might get *redirected* to a different origin (as it tells jQuery not to add extra headers to the request which would require a preflight OPTIONS request to get permissions for CORS which it adds if the URL given points to the same origin). You still need the server the request is being made to to give permission with CORS.

Comment: Agree with that, I'm using this scenario in cordova app, where I can call remote url in my app by allowing CROS permissions. and it runs perfectly as well.